# Typescript how to declare a method that returns the object it's called for (this)

Tags: javascript, typescript

How to write a declaration for **on** function.
The **on** function has to return a dynamic type based on the object it's called for.

```
function on(type, handler) {
    this.addEventListener(arguments);

    return this;
}

var element = document.getElementById('elm');
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();

element.on = on; // => element.on(t,cb) must return element 
request.on = on; // => request.on(t,cb) must return request
```

Here is my d.ts (this is just example, this is incorrect at ThisType)

```
declare function on<K extends keyof WindowEventMap>(type: string, handler: 
(this: ThisType, ev: WindowEventMap[K]) => any): ThisType;
```

I don't know if Typescript has another keywords to solve this problem. (***ThisCaller***)

Comment: Rather than focusing on the type declaration, how are you planning on returning the caller _at all_?

Comment: line 4 "return this;" will return caller.

Comment: `this` isn't the caller though?

Comment: @NguyễnHoàngĐôngPhương It's called 'context', not 'caller'

Comment: OK I am wrong with names, but how to write declaration for on function that return its 'context'?

Comment: You can use `this` as a return type.

Comment: Did you try it? if 'on' place inside a interface this referent to the interface. this can't be used as context. let try it code is ready to try

Comment: Then return the name of the interface? I'm not sure what the problem is.

Answer (score 1):

TypeScript has a feature called [polymorphic **this** types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#polymorphic-this-types) which can be used here.

However, this assignment

```
element.on = on;
```

will be marked as error because in TypeScript, you can't add arbitrary property to an object just by assigning to that property.

You can do that in a type-safe way by adding a function that will add `on` property to an object, and return that same object but declared with appropriate type, telling the compiler that it now has that `on` property:

```
interface EventListeners {
    addEventListener(type: string, handler: () => void): void;
};

function on<T extends EventListeners>(this: T, type: string, handler: () => void): T {
    this.addEventListener(type, handler);

    return this;
}


var element = document.getElementById('elm');
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();

// had to declare this interface in order to use this as return type
interface EventListenersExt extends EventListeners {
    on(type: string, handler: () => void): this;
}
function addOn<T extends EventListeners>(t: T): T & EventListenersExt {
    return Object.assign(t, { on });
}

const elementExt = addOn(element); 
const requestExt = addOn(request);

const e = elementExt.on('click', () => { }).on('keyup', () => { }); // const e: HTMLElement & EventListenersExt
const r = requestExt.on('load', () => { }); // const r: XMLHttpRequest & EventListenersExt
```

Comment: I just realized you edited my question. Actually I don't write my code in Typescript, I only use Typescript as declaration file (.d.ts). I read your answer adding  <T>(this: T as first argument it worked every well:

declare function on<K extends keyof WindowEventMap, T>(this: T, type: string, handler:
    (this: T, ev: WindowEventMap[K]) => any): T;

But It only work well when not place inside any interface. I think the problem come from Typescript itself.